# Pagination with native query in slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, pagination, slick

I am using Slick to connect to Postgres Database in our application. I have a generic filtering logic, where a Filter object will be passed from the UI, and it should return results with pagination. The Filter object should be generic so that it can be re-used. 
Pseudo code of filter object is given below:

```
Filter = {
type: table
prop: List_of_conditions
page : 1
size : 10
}
```

Currently, I am building a native SQL from the Filter object and executing it. However, I am not able to use `take` and `drop` before the query is actually getting executed. It is currently getting all the results, and then dropping the unnecessary records.
I know how to do it with the slick queries, but not sure how to use pagination with the native queries?

```
val res = StaticQuery.queryNA[Entity](queryStr).list.drop((filter.pageNo- 1) * filter.pageSize).take(filter.pageSize)
```

I am using `Slick 2.1`

Comment: The problem with static query is that you can write anything in it, for example let's say you have this query: `SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 10`, then you ask slick to add a `GROUP BY` clause, slick cannot assure the order of the clause (and thus that there are no syntax error in your SQL), in fact no usual method is available for static queries, you will have to build it in your `queryStr` parameter.

Comment: hmm :( Isn't there any way to convert the `where condition string` into slick expression ?

Comment: Why don't you use the normal slick syntax? This query doesn't seems like something so complicated that you need plain SQL, the features used in your query are all available in the slick library.

Comment: @EndeNeu, Could you please show me a sample to build the slick expression from the Filter Object? I recently switched to scala from java and not yet completely got into scala way.

Comment: It is not exactly allowing the user to query any table. Just to clear my requirement, I ll explain. There are particular rest endpoints which allows filtering with pagination. In the REST controller side, the filter json is converted into filter object, then set a field for specifying the table(ie. the allowed tables are set in the rest controller, user doesnt have permission). The user will provide only the where condition required for the filtering and the page size and page number. Hope I am able to explain the requiremtn

Answer (score 1):

When you are using plain sql, you can't use the collection operators to build a query. You have to do it all in SQL:

```
val limit = filter.pageSize
val offset = (filter.pageNo- 1) * filter.pageSize
val res = StaticQuery.queryNA[Entity](queryStr ++ s" LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset").list
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but i would suggest you to try to move `.list` call to the end

```
val res = StaticQuery.queryNA[Entity](queryStr).drop((filter.pageNo- 1) * filter.pageSize).take(filter.pageSize).list
```

Comment: No, this wont work since queryNA doesnt have drop and take methods